# CSS arrow not straight

Tags: css

My arrow is very slightly bended, how can I make it perfectly straight?

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  position: relative;
}

div:after {
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  border: solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border-top-color: blue;
  border-top-width: 35px;
  border-right-width: 35px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: You just linked to `https://jsfiddle.net/`, not any specific one. And with your reputation level, you should already know that a [mre] needs to be contained in your question itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't define the border width of the transparent border (first parameter). In this case the browser takes a default value (in this case 3px) which cause the angle on the left side. You have to set the border width of the transparent border to 0 to solve this issue:

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  position: relative;
}

div:after {
  border: 0 solid transparent;
  border-top-color: blue;
  border-top-width: 35px;
  border-right-width: 35px;
  content: "";
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```